# Excel: Compare DateTime to Date

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I am using conditional formatting with formulas to highlight dates that occur today (or in the past) in some colour. To check whether a date occurs today, I simply use `A1=TODAY()`, which works fine. However, some cells contain datetimes, such as `25-Mar-2014 11:14 PM`. When I use the above formula on that cell, it returns `FALSE`, even though today is the 25th of March.

What is the correct way to determine whether a datetime occurs today? I have tried using `DATE(A1)` to convert the cell to a date without time, but that does not work. I do not want to use Visual Basic for this, nor do something like `AND(A1<tomorrow;A1>yesterday)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that `DATE` is not used like you mentioned. It is used like so:

```
=DATE(year, month, date)
```

You can perhaps use `INT` which rounds down to the nearest integer (so `25-Mar-2014 11:14 PM` becomes `25-Mar-2014 00:00:00` just like `TODAY()`):

```
=INT(A1)=TODAY()
```

Comment: Fantastic! I had totally forgotten about how dates and times are stored in Excel. This is quite a neat trick. Thank you very much!